# app screen height and width not expanding to fit iphone 6 in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi i switched to xcode 7 recently, and as usual some starting problems arises when switching to new ides. 
The screen width and height of my app is still set for iphone 5 when am actually running it on iphone 6. This was not happening in xcode 6 it used to render properly for both phone models.

[image: Screen size not fitting]

You can see the tab bar buttons ending little higher than bottom and screen is not expanded completely to the right.

Is there any launch image or any other setting i need to add to make screen size fit for all devices.

I have the following settings in my xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you have to check that you had enabled Size Classes

[image: To enable size classes]

Secondly, you need to set the constraints at the storyboard accordingly

Answer (score 0):

*

```
Unchecking "Use Size Classes" option and then coming back and re-checking it again fixes this issue.

1. In the project navigator, select a storyboard or xib file.

2. The file’s contents open in Interface Builder.

3. Choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.

4. In the Interface Builder Document section, un-tick the "Use Size      Classes" checkbox.

5. Leave the menu. Come back and tick the "Use Size Classes" checkbox again.
```

*